# Scrape data from Omnibug console?

Tags: web-scraping, tagging, adobe-analytics, developer-tools

I am using Omnibug to analyze the data my company is tracking on our site. I'd like to go through each page and harvest the Omnibug data in order to create a table for our data tagging documentation. We have around 600 pages so I want to automate this process. Does anybody know how I can go about scraping the data Omnibug produces? It is a Developer Tools plugin on Chrome so any advice on how to scrape data from the Developer Tools interface would also be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Working on doing something similar in  python, accessing the har report may help https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network

Comment: Adobe offers a [js bookmark debugger](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/debugger_install.html). You can take a look at what they do

Comment: I am also looking for answer of this question, please let me know if you found out any solution.

Comment: @PankajKumarKatiyar - Omnibug allows for exporting the raw data (not broken out by variables). We're working on a better export system though.